# Play framework: service to service continuous communication

Tags: scala, service, playframework, playframework-2.0

I need some advice/insight how to best implement certain functionality. The idea of my task is live system monitoring dashboard.

Let's say I have a following setup based on two physical servers:

**Server1** is running Play application which monitors certain files, services, etc for changes. As soon as change occurs it alerts another Play application running on Server2.

**Server2** is running a Play application that serves a web front end displaying live dashboard data being sent to it from Play application sitting on Server1.

I am only familiar with Play framework in a way that it serves data to http requests, but the way I need it to run in this particular situation is a bit different.

My question is how do I keep these two Play applications in constant connection the way I've described above? The requirement is that Server1 application would be pushing data to Server2 application on a need basis as opposed to Server2 application running in an endless loop and asking Server1 application if there is any new data every 5 seconds.

I'm using Play Framework 2.2.1 with Scala.

Comment: Can you tell me why they are two separate Play applications ?

Comment: @VenkatSudheerReddyAedama Because there can be multiple Server1s (production server) and just one Server2 (monitoring server). I can't use JSONP either, it's just too limited for my needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually [`Akka`](http://akka.io/) introduced in Play 2.0 perfectly fits your requirements (*as Venkat pointed*).

Combining its *remoting*, *scheduler* and *futures* possibilities you will be able to build every monitor you need.

Scanerio may be ie:

- S1 let's name it a **Doctor** uses Akka's scheduler to monitor resources each several seconds
- if **Doctor** detects changes sends Akka message to S2's actor (**FrontEnd**) otherwise does nothing.
- Mentioned actor of **FrontEnd** can add event to some *queue*, or push it directly ie to some WebSocket, which will push it to browser. Other option is setting another *scheduler* at **FrontEnd** which will check if *queue*  contains new events.

Check included sample applications how you can communicate your **FrontEnd** with browser (ie. [`commet-live-monitoring`](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/tree/2.2.x/samples/scala/comet-live-monitoring) or [`eventsource-clock`](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/tree/2.2.x/samples/scala/eventsource-clock)).

For communication between a **Doctor** and **FrontEnd** apps, `akka-remote` is promising feature.

Comment: Thanks, I kinda realise that what I want to do is possible, I just don't know how. Some more details, explanation, a pseudo example is all I need.

Comment: Sorry, can't give you sample code (would need to test approach first), but in edit you'll find some tips, make best usage of it ;) Also check   Venkat's answer as it describes good approach as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think Server-Sent Events (SSE: http://dev.w3.org/html5/eventsource/) are what you are looking for. Since it's supposed to be only one-directional push (server1 pushes data to server2), SSE is probably a better choice over WebSockets which are full-duplex bidirectional connections. Since your Server2 has a web-front end, the browser can automatically reconnect to Server1 if you are using SSE. Most modern browsers support SSE (IE doesn't).

Since you are using Play Framework: You can use Play WS API for Service to Service communication and also you can take advantage of the powerful abstractions for handling data asynchronously like Enumerator and Iteratee. As Play! integrates seamlessly with Akka, you can manage/supervise the HTTP connection using Actors.

Edit:

Answering "How exactly one service can push data to another on a need basis" in steps:

1. Manage the HTTP connection: Server1 needs to have a WebService client to manage HTTP connection with Server2. By "manage HTTP connection" I mean: reconnect/reset/disconnect the HTTP connection. Akka Actors are a great usecase for solving this problem. Basically this actor receives messages like CONNECT, CHECK_CONN_STATUS, DISCONNECT, RESET etc. Have a scheduler for your HttpSupervisor actor to check the connection status, so that you can reconnect if the connection is dead.

   val system = ActorSystem("Monitor")

   val supervisorRef = system.actorOf(Props(new HttpSupervisor(system.eventStream)), "MonitorSupervisor")

   system.scheduler.schedule(60 seconds, 60 seconds, supervisorRef, CHECK_CONN_STATUS)
2. Listen to the changes and PUSH on need:
   Create an Enumerator which produces the changes. Create an Iteratee for consuming the changes asynchronously. Again, some code that may be of help:

   val monitorIteratee = play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee.foreach[Array[Byte]]
   (WS.url(postActionURLOnServer2).post(new String(_, "UTF-8")))

Attach the iteratee to the enumerator.

Comment: I knew most of the things you've pointed out, but it doesn't answer my question. How is it exactly that I make one service to push data to another on a need basis?